# Duplicate lang item error (E0152) with sp_io crate when integrating Frontier pallets with Substrate

Tags: substrate-node-template, evm, frontier

I'm trying to make my `Substrate-based blockchain` compatible with Solidity and `MetaMask`. I've cloned Substrate from the `polkadot-v0.9.39` branch and am trying to `integrate Frontier's Ethereum` compatibility pallets, specifically `pallet-ethereum` and `pallet-evm`.

My Cargo.toml dependencies look like this:

```rs
    fp-rpc = { default-features = false, branch="polkadot-v0.9.39", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git" }
    fp-self-contained = { default-features = false, branch="polkadot-v0.9.39", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git" }
    pallet-dynamic-fee = { default-features = false, branch="polkadot-v0.9.39", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git" }
    pallet-ethereum = { default-features = false, branch="polkadot-v0.9.39", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git" }
    pallet-evm = { default-features = false, branch="polkadot-v0.9.39", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git" }
    pallet-evm-precompile-modexp = { default-features = false, branch="polkadot-v0.9.39", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git" }
    pallet-evm-precompile-sha3fips = { default-features = false, branch="polkadot-v0.9.39", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git" }
    pallet-evm-precompile-simple = { default-features = false, branch="polkadot-v0.9.39", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git" }
    pallet-base-fee = { default-features = false, branch="polkadot-v0.9.39", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git" }
```

However, when I add the following code:

```rs
        use pallet_ethereum::{Call::transact, Transaction as EthereumTransaction};
    use pallet_evm::{Account as EVMAccount, EnsureAddressTruncated, HashedAddressMapping, Runner};

I get this error:

        error[E0152]: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on): `panic_impl`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `kitchensink_runtime` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/kianoush/projects/hearvers/target/debug/wbuild/kitchensink-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-b8b7b73b41341229.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/kianoush/projects/hearvers/target/debug/wbuild/kitchensink-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-e1bd7f9d1961d62b.rmeta
    
    For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0152`.
    warning: `kitchensink-runtime` (lib) generated 3 warnings
    error: could not compile `kitchensink-runtime` due to previous error; 3 warnings emitted
    warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

How can I resolve this `sp_io conflict`? I'm finding it difficult to align the `sp_io` versions used by `kitchensink-runtime` and `frame_support`. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check `std` feature, this error is mostly about that some dependencies are missed in `std` feature in `Cargo.toml`